# Grouping by a variable, sorting, and printing values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Subject': [101,101,101,101,101,101,101,101,101,102,102,102,102,102,102,102,102,102],
                   'Accuracy': [2, 0, 0, 0,4,4,6,4,3,3,3,6,6,6,4,3,2,7],
                   'Distance': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                   'Onset': [1,7,8,9,1,5,5,3,2,6,7,8,9,5,4,3,2,4]})
```

For each subject, I want to print a csv that contains the Onsets for each distance. And the onsets would be sorted in ascending order. For example, file_Subject101_Distance1.csv would look like:

```
1 7 8
```

file_Subject101_Distance2.csv would be:

```
1 5 9
```

(because they'd be sorted) and so on. I can sort in pandas and have used 'groupby' but don't understand how to use them together to do what I want (or if that is even the best way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### IIUC

```
for (s, d), g in df.groupby(['Subject', 'Distance']).Onset:
    with open(f"file_Subject{s}_Distance{d}.csv", mode='w') as fh:
        fh.write(" ".join(g.sort_values().astype(str)))
```

Comment: this is almost perfect! but the #s in the csv files are not ordered

Comment: Updated.  Check now.